# Xcode UI testing can't be used to dismiss KeyChain access dialog

Tags: objective-c, macos, xcode-ui-testing

My application requires access to the KeyChain when first started. Therefore, whenever new build is launched, a system dialog pops up asking permissions from the user for my application to access the KeyChain. This, however, blocks UI testing completely - the `XCUIApplication`'s `launch` call is synchronous, so there is no way to dismiss this dialog programmatically.

How can I workaround this problem?

Comment: Unlock the keychain before starting the app?

Comment: isn't it time-bounded? this is the part of Xcode Continuous Integration, so the app is tested and started by the bot whenever.

Comment: On closer inspection, unlocking the keychain is not going to work. The app has to be added to the trusted applications. This can be done in code. Another option is to allow all applications access to the keychain item.